# includegraphics - Problem with compiling

Tags: graphics

I am actually writing a latex file in which I would like to insert pictures. I have the following preambule:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
```

In my text, I tried to insert a picture with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
 \begin{picture}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Deltoidalicositetrahedron.jpg}
 \end{picture}
\end{figure}
```

I am using TexShop version 2.38 and I tried to compile with LaTeX. It worked on the computer of a friend using the same TexShop version. However on my computer it doesn't work. Here is what the console complains about:

```
./bio mol adn.tex:57: Use of \pictur@ doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \includegraphics 

l.57   \includegraphics
                       [scale=0.5]{Deltoidalicositetrahedron.jpg}

?
```

Has anyone ever encounter the same problem?

As usual, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does removing the `.jpg` help?

Comment: I don't think you need the `picture` environment, either...

Comment: In a normal latex this can never work. The picture environment (which is the wrong environment anyway) expects an argument in round braces (coordinates). Use simply the `\includegraphics`. Use the figure-environment around it, if you want your graphics to float.

Comment: Even without the picture environment it does not work. The .jpg extension is no problem either.

Comment: If you're still getting error messages after removing the picture environment, doesn't the error message change?  That information would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I've had a similar problem. Try without the scale and it worked with me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147733)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can  use the picture environment but you need to proceed like that :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}      
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

In my text, I tried to insert a picture with the preceding code:

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm} % fix unit

\newsavebox{\mybox} 
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Deltoidalicositetrahedron.jpg}} 
% we save the picture

 \begin{figure}
   \begin{picture}(6,4) % you need to add dimensions 
  \put(0,0){\usebox{\mybox}}
   \end{picture}   
 \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Now you can use macros from picture to decorate or add what you want

With a picture

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 

In my text, I tried to insert a picture with the preceding code:
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\newsavebox{\mybox} 
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ant.png}} 
 \begin{figure}
   \begin{picture}(8,6)
  \put(0,0){\usebox{\mybox}} 
  \put(2,2.5){\oval(6,5)}
   \end{picture}   
 \end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible with the dimensions of `\mybox` (`\wd\mybox` `\ht\mybox` and `\dp\mybox`) to set the dimensions of the picture environment. If the OP  don't need the picture environment, I agree with the others comments.

Comment: As I said in the other comments, the picture environment is not the problem.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, the  picture environment is the problem, because you use it with a bad manner. You need to add (x,y) dimensions of the picture! I compile your code so you can use the picture environment but correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Following Seamus and Ulrike this is all you need:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Deltoidalicositetrahedron.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The picture environment is not the problem. Even without it it does not work.